# Authentication in the Iconomi API in PHP

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am developing a PHP script to consume the Iconomi API, but I have problems with authentication.

According to the [documentation](https://iconomi-ag.github.io/iconomi-api/#section/Introduction/Authentication), you have to create a signature and attach it in the header. However the curl_exec function returns false, which means it has failed.

These are the instructions:

> Creating a request
> All REST requests must contain the following headers:

> - ICN-API-KEY - The api key as a string.
> - ICN-SIGN - The base64-encoded signature (see Signing a Message).
> - ICN-TIMESTAMP - A timestamp for your request in epoch milliseconds.

> Signing a Message
> You generate the ICN-SIGN header by creating a sha512 HMAC using the base64-decoded secret key on the > prehash string timestamp + method + requestPath + body (where + represents string concatenation) and base64-encode the output, where:

> - the timestamp value is the same as the ICN-TIMESTAMP header.
> - the body is the request body string or omitted if there is no request body (typically for GET requests).
> - method must always be in upper case

And this is my code:

```
function call_iconomi_api()
{
    $url = 'https://api.iconomi.com';
    $api_key = get_field('iconomi_api_key', 'option');
    $api_secret = get_field('iconomi_api_secret', 'option');
    $timestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
    $request_path = '/v1/assets';
    $message = $timestamp . 'GET' . $request_path;
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha512', $message, $api_secret));

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url . $request_path);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'ICN-API-KEY: ' . $api_key,
        'ICN-SIGN: ' . $signature,
        'ICN-TIMESTAMP: ' . $timestamp
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified those `get_field` calls returned the proper values you expected in the first place? Have you used static values in those places for testing?

Comment: Is the secret already base64-decoded?

Comment: @CBroe, yes, the variables $api_key and $api_secret return the correct values in as string (example: 1920258c97f89e708db1a442389f5359e3ac919a6c6893d10ad1387275bbcae0)

Comment: Have a look at their reference implementation in Python: https://github.com/iconomi-ag/iconomi-python/blob/master/main_test.py

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha512', $message, $api_secret, true));
```

If you look into https://iconomi-ag.github.io/iconomi-api/#section/Introduction/Authentication under section "Signing a Message" (Example of GET with query parameters) this function with last param as **true** returns identical string as base64 encoded signature

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How can this possibly work? Passing `true` as the last argument instructs `hash_hmac` to generate a binary value, which will simply not work when passed to an HTTP header.

Comment: return value of this function then needs to be base64 encoded (as mentioned in docs)